# CSS FlexBox Not Wrapping Inside Table in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

Looking at the following code. When you view it in Chrome the inner td content is wrapping but in Internet Explorer 11 the content is not wrapping.

Please help :)

JS [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bKM9/5/)

CSS

```
 .flexbox {
     min-height:60px;
     height:60px;
     align-items: center;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;          
 }
 .moreblue {
     background-color: blue;
 }
 .moregreen {
     background-color: darkgreen;
 }
 .red {
     background-color: red;
 }
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <td>
            <div class="flexbox moregreen">CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT</div>
        </td>
    </thead>
</table>
<table>
    <thead>
        <td>
            <div class="moreblue">CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT</div>
        </td>
    </thead>
</table>
<div class="flexbox red">CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT</div>
```

Comment: Forgive me, but why would you use flexbox inside a table?

Comment: I have several items I'm aligning vertical center. Flexbox in chrome gave me a good result to achieve this.

Comment: My question is why use a table...it's going backwards to use an advanced layout method like flexbox in a 1990's layout method of using a table.

Comment: @Paulie_D I ran into this problem too. My application already has a table layout on the outside, and the new page I'm adding can only meet the requirements if I use flexbox or rearrange with Javascript for different screen widths. We'd all love to use the newest and shiniest, but sometimes we have to deal with legacy code.